# CSV Upload - Unable to Merge duplicate records to insert as one record

Tags: apex

[image]

In the below pic `column[0]`, `column[1]`, `column[2]` gets inserted in `Account` object and `column[3]` gets inserted in `Type__c` object.

Taking reference `column[0]` I am checking duplicate.

For the fist two records I am able to merge `column[0]`, `column[1]`, `column[2]`  as one record and insert it in `Account` object.

But I am unable to merge `column[3]` to one record and insert it to `Type__c` object.

```
public class importDataFromCSVController 
{
    public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
    public string csvAsString{get;set;}
    public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
    public List<account> acclist{get;set;}
    public map<string, string> csvmap = new map<string, string>();
    public map<string, Account> accmap = new map<string, Account>();
    List<Type__c> typeList = new List<Type__c>();

    public importDataFromCSVController()
    {
        csvFileLines = new String[]{};
        acclist = New List<Account>(); 
    }

    public void importCSVFile(){
        try
        {
            csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
            csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n'); 

            for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++)
            {

                string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
                if(csvmap.containsKey(csvRecordData[0]))
                {
                    csvmap.put(csvRecordData[0],csvmap.get(csvRecordData[0])+','+csvRecordData[2]);
                }
                else
                {
                    csvmap.put(csvRecordData[0],csvRecordData[2]) ;
                }
            }

            for(string str : csvmap.keyset())
            {
                Account accObj = new Account() ;
                accObj.name = str ;             
                accObj.test__c= csvmap.get(str);                                                                      
                accmap.put(str , accObj); 
            }

            insert accmap.values();

            Map<Id, set<string>> typeAccMap = new Map<Id, set<string>>();

            for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++)
            {
                string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');

                if(accmap.containsKey(csvRecordData[0]))
                {
                    Account acc = accmap.get(csvRecordData[0]);

                    if(typeAccMap.containsKey(acc.id))
                    {
                        Set<String> typeSet = typeAccMap.get(acc.id);

                        if(! typeSet.contains(csvRecordData[3]))
                        {   
                            Type__c t = new Type__c (Name = csvRecordData[3], Account__c = acc.id); 
                            typeList.add(t);

                            Set<string> tmpSet = typeAccMap.get(csvRecordData[0]);
                            tmpSet.add(Id.valueOf(csvRecordData[3]));
                            typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], tmpSet);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Type__c t = new Type__c (Name = csvRecordData[3], Account__c = acc.id); 
                        typeList.add(t);
                        typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], new Set<String>{csvRecordData[3]});
                    }
                }

                upsert typeList;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured while importin data Please make sure input csv file is correct');
            ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
        }  
    }
}
```

For first 2 rows the data which is getting inserted is as below

```
Account Name - GenePoint Test
Account Number - CC978213,CD355119-A
```

Child Object - Type__c should get inserted as below -

```
Only one record
1. Name - Customer - Channel

Instead of 
1. Name - Customer - Channel

2. Name - Customer - Channel
```

Comment: Is there some code missing?  There's no reference to a `Type__c` object anywhere in your code.

Comment: Hi Nick.. sorry for the confusion.. I hv updated my code.

Comment: When you say "I am unable to merge column[3] to one record and insert it to Type__c object", do you get an error? What happens? What do you want to happen?  You really need to be more clear with your questions.

Comment: instead of inserting -  Customer - Channel -  two times.. i want to insert it for 1 time in Types__c.. Type__c is a child of Account object..

Comment: But aren't there 3 different accounts there?  In which case, you'd need 3 different Types?

Comment: Hi Nick.. I have updated my questionn above..

Comment: You really need to take the time to clean up your code before posting here.  It would make it a lot easier for people to help you.  Your code has commented out sections, and there is even one part where there are debug statements between an if statement and the opening curly brace.  This makes it exceedingly hard for people to help you.  People won't want to take time out of there day to help you if you're not willing to take the time to clean up your own code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class importDataFromCSVController 
    {
        public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
        public string csvAsString{get;set;}
        public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
        public List<account> acclist{get;set;}
        public map<string, string> csvmap = new map<string, string>();
        public map<string, Account> accmap = new map<string, Account>();
        List<Type__c> typeList = new List<Type__c>();

        public importDataFromCSVController()
        {
            csvFileLines = new String[]{};
            acclist = New List<Account>(); 
        }

        public void importCSVFile(){
            try
            {
                csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
                csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n'); 

                for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++)
                {

                    string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
                    if(csvmap.containsKey(csvRecordData[0]))
                    {
                        csvmap.put(csvRecordData[0],csvmap.get(csvRecordData[0])+','+csvRecordData[2]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        csvmap.put(csvRecordData[0],csvRecordData[2]) ;
                    }
                }

                for(string str : csvmap.keyset())
                {
                    Account accObj = new Account() ;
                    accObj.name = str ;             
                    accObj.test__c= csvmap.get(str);                                                                      
                    accmap.put(str , accObj); 
                }

                insert accmap.values();
                Map<String, Set<String>> accountIDtoTypes = new Map<String, Set<String>>();

                Map<Id, set<string>> typeAccMap = new Map<Id, set<string>>();

                for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++)
                {
                    string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');

                    if(accmap.containsKey(csvRecordData[0]) && 
(!accountIDtoTypes.containskey(csvRecordData[0]) || (accountIDtoTypes.containskey(csvRecordData[0]) &&
!accountIDtoTypes.get(svRecordData[0]).contains(svRecordData[3]))))
                    {
                        if(accountIDtoTypes.containsKey(csvRecordData[0]))
                        {
                            accountIDtoTypes.get(csvRecordData[0]).add(csvRecordData[3]);
                        } else {
                            accountIDtoTypes.put(csvRecordData[0],new Set<String>{csvRecordData[3]});
                        }
                        Account acc = accmap.get(csvRecordData[0]);

                        if(typeAccMap.containsKey(acc.id))
                        {
                            Set<String> typeSet = typeAccMap.get(acc.id);

                            if(! typeSet.contains(csvRecordData[3]))
                            {   
                                Type__c t = new Type__c (Name = csvRecordData[3], Account__c = acc.id); 
                                typeList.add(t);

                                Set<string> tmpSet = typeAccMap.get(csvRecordData[0]);
                                tmpSet.add(Id.valueOf(csvRecordData[3]));
                                typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], tmpSet);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Type__c t = new Type__c (Name = csvRecordData[3], Account__c = acc.id); 
                            typeList.add(t);
                            typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], new Set<String>{csvRecordData[3]});
                        }
                    }

                    upsert typeList;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured while importin data Please make sure input csv file is correct');
                ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Andrei...Customer - Direct...the last row should get inserted in Type__c..but its not happening...duplicate check for first two rows is working correctly...can u plz check..

Comment: I can not get 100% what your requirements are. This code will insert 1 Type__c per AccountID.  see image 
https://s18.postimg.org/8qecoyuyx/what2.jpg

Comment: ok from ur pic...forth row should get inserted as a child to 001..So 001 will have child object as 2 records TypeA, TypeB...Same for 002..

Comment: do you also need to insert row 3 from my example? as it is TypeB

Comment: Changed to insert all unique child. I did not touched rest of your code but it needs to be refactored as well in my opinion.

Comment: i am getting error ..Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Set<String>].put(String) at line 60 column 68 ...

Comment: it should be .add i think..

Comment: yes, changed it to add